# Call a specific function every time Main_activity is loaded?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have created an application where in oncreate i am calling a function overlay(), which puts an overlay above the application. Then there are multiple screens that user can browse. My problem is I want when user Goes back to the Main screen that function should be again called and that overlay can be seen.Is there something i can use?

Comment: move it to `onResume()`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code in your mainActivity

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first
        overlay();
    }
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining for the OP *why* that  code should be added and what it changes?